# move_arm and arm_controller conflict over action interface message type

Tags: ros, pr2-controller-manager, move-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I changed in move_arm.launch from

```
<param name="controller_action_name" type="string" value="arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory" />
```

to

```
<param name="controller_action_name" type="string" value="arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action" />
```

and hence my move_arm.launch is

```
<launch>
    <node pkg="move_arm" type="move_arm_simple_action" name="arm_tilt_laser_move_arm">
        <param name="group" type="string" value="arm" />
        <remap from="arm_ik" to="arm_tilt_laser_arm_kinematics/get_constraint_aware_ik" />
        <param name="controller_action_name" type="string" value="arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action" />
        <!--<param name="controller_action_name" type="string" value="arm_controller/follow_joint_trajectory" />-->
    </node>
</launch>
```

because my arm_controller is looking for arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action/goal ;arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action/cancel ....etc

and got the following error:

```
[ERROR] [1320368664.906687128, 19.071000000]: Client [/arm_controller/arm_joint_trajectory_action_node] wants topic /arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action/goal to have datatype/md5sum [pr2_controllers_msgs/JointTrajectoryActionGoal/aee77e81e3afb8d91af4939d603609d8], but our version has [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionGoal/8f3e00277a7b5b7c60e1ac5be35ddfa2]. Dropping connection.
[ERROR] [1320368664.909130373, 19.103000000]: Client [/arm_tilt_laser_move_arm] wants topic /arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action/result to have datatype/md5sum [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionResult/bce83d50f7bb28226801436caf0e2043], but our version has [pr2_controllers_msgs/JointTrajectoryActionResult/1eb06eeff08fa7ea874431638cb52332]. Dropping connection.
[ERROR] [1320368664.909281089, 19.103000000]: Client [/arm_tilt_laser_move_arm] wants topic /arm_controller/joint_trajectory_action/feedback to have datatype/md5sum [control_msgs/FollowJointTrajectoryActionFeedback/868e86353778bcb1c5689adaa01a40d7], but our version has [pr2_controllers_msgs/JointTrajectoryActionFeedback/aae20e09065c3809e8a8e87c4c8953fd]. Dropping connection.
```

I can understand from the error that move_arm being an action client (while interfacing to controller) is sending a goal message which is not of same type as arm_controller node action server listening to. same for feedback and result message type.
I am using electric.

Is it because of new arm_navigation stack that move_arm message types has been changed for interfacing with arm_controller??
Anyone got this problem before? Need help please.

Thanks,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11792/move_arm-and-arm_controller-conflict-over-action-interface-message-type/) by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 373 on 2011-11-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See my answer: http://answers.ros.org/question/2765/where-is-the-node-for-follow_joint_trajectory

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1